# setInverval delay only working first time

Tags: jquery

my setInterval code is working fine the first time, but it's not repeating correctly -- after the first time it's not delaying inbetween the first and second instance. Is this an issue with my code or with setInterval?

```
    setInterval(function() {

        $('#img2').fadeIn(500).delay(5000).fadeOut(500);

    }, 5000);
```

For clarification (if my code is really botched!) I want my img to fade in after 5 seconds, stay there for 5 seconds, and then fade out -- 5 seconds later fade in, stay for 5 seconds, fade out; repeat.

edit: For further clarification, I think I need to ask instead: Is there a way to account for the delay *in* the function when setting an interval? Right now my interval is occurring at the same time as my delay within the function, and it's causing the time between intervals to be 0.

Thanks all!

Comment: The `delay(5000)` means that the next repetition of `setInterval` will have already started before the delay finishes.

Comment: The time for `delay` and `setInterval` are same.  try changing it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast responses! A bit confused here.. I changed the setInterval time to 10000 and while that makes the times between executes of the function 5 seconds, it makes the initial one 10 seconds! Is there any way to keep the initial firing 5 seconds as well as the rest of the intervals 5 seconds delay? Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

`setInterval()` just starts the function on a repeating time schedule, it doesn't base the repetitions on how long each one takes. Use `setTimeout` to schedule the restart a fixed time after each one ends.

```
function delay_and_fade() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#img2').fadeIn(500).delay(5000).fadeOut(500);
        delay_and_fade();
    }, 5000);
}

delay_and_fade();
```

Answer (score 1):

try using this.

```
setInterval(function() {
$('#img2').fadeIn(500);
$('#img2').delay(5000);
$('#img2').fadeOut(500);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: This is still starting the next interval right after the last one :( thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MaSgL/)

```
setInterval(function() {
  $('img').fadeIn(500).delay(500).fadeOut(500);
}, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! However when I change the values to 5000 for delay and the setInterval time, it's the same as my current code, which doesn't work :( I need it to be 5 seconds delay after it fades in, and 5 seconds of delay after it fades out before the next interval starts

Comment: you can try 500 500 500 1000

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the responses! I was able to fix it by changing my code to this:

```
    setInterval(function() {

        $('#img2').fadeIn(500).delay(5000).fadeOut(500).delay(5000);

    }, 5000);
```

By adding a delay after my fadeout it keeps 5 seconds between each interval and it has a 5 second delay at the start! Just what I was wanting :-)

Comment: Careful there, if I understand your code correctly you will be overlapping and possibly creating an animation queue. At 5000ms it starts, at 5500 (5000+500) the fadeIn is finished and it will delay for 5000. At 10,000 (5000+5000) the setInterval fires again and adds another bunch of items to the queue. At 10,500 (5000+500+5000) the first delay is finished and it starts the fadeOut. 11,000 fadeOut is done and it starts the 5000 delay. 15,000 setInterval first again, adds another to queue (3rd queue). 16,000 2nd delay of 1st queue finishes, 2nd queue starts.

Answer (score 0):

You have two distinct issue here.

1. You want your fadeIn/Out animation to start after a 5 second delay.
2. You want the animation to restart 5 seconds after it finishes.

To have your animation repeat every 5 seconds:

```
function fadeAnimation() {
    $('#img2').fadeIn(500).delay(5000).fadeOut(500);
    // this executes immediately, so add 500+5000+500 (6000) to the time
    // to account for the animation time
    setTimeout(fadeAnimation, 5000 + 6000);
}
```

To set your animation to start after 5 seconds:

```
setTimeout(fadeAnimation, 5000);
```

Does that make sense?